# Why does the linux 'file' command tell me my Python file is a Java file?

Tags: python, linux, file

I was doing some work on the command line and I noticed something strange when I used a wildcard, a python source file (in my case it was a file called `echo.py`) was marked as being a **UTF-8 Unicode Java program text** file, which it clearly is not.

Could someone tell me why `file` is giving me an invalid output? This is the command I used:

```
$ file echo.py
echo.py: UTF-8 Unicode Java program text, with CRLF line terminators
```

This is a snippet of code from the file itself:

```
# coding=utf-8
from re import IGNORECASE

def echo(message):
    print(message)
    something_else(message)

-- snip --
```

Comment: `file` uses heuristics so it will not be always right.

Comment: The data file of `file` is called [`magic`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) but, rest assured, it doesn't actually use magic at all. An example from http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufile.htm: ".. running the file command listing any file ending with .txt: [...]index.txt: ASCII Java program text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators" – which most likely *also* is not really Java source code.